# large data is broken while sending from javascript ajax to servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am accepting data from HTML Textarea. The data is nothing but copied HTML files with inline CSS. When I submit the data to servlet using javascript ajax, only some amount, say 20% is read by servlet. I am not able to get it as entered.I tried adding `maxPostSize="0"` in `server.xml` file,but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the code and data you are sending from javascript ajax.

Comment: http_request.open("POST",'UploadServlet?sheetName='+sname+'&userName='+name+'&password='+pass+'&emailBody='+emailBody+'&emailSubject='+emailSubject,false);
   http_request.send();

Comment: you can alert this part with actual values- UploadServlet?sheetName='+sname+'&userName='+name+'&pa‌​ssword='+pass+'&emailBody='+emailBody+'&emailSubject='+emailSubject   may be you can get some hint there..

Comment: There is no error,but I am not able to get whole string in servlet. My servlet is showing just 20% of original string.

Comment: I suspect there is single quote somewhere in the data of your variables...which is truncating your main string in between.. Please check variable values..

Comment: I solved this issue. I am using encoding type as multipart and reading the large string as InputStream :D